# Get filtered data from JSON in angular 6+

Tags: angular, mongodb, typescript

In my code I have this data extracted from a mongoDb colleciton and I want to count how many time `gapValidations[0].gapMapping[x].entities[i].value` is equal to `gapValidations[length -1].gapMapping[x].entities[i].value`only and only if they have the same `gapValidations[z].gapMapping[x].entities[i].docId` and they are of the same `gapValidations[length -1].gapMapping[x].entities[i].type`.

[image: console]

I think it is all related on how I get my data in my service. Right now my service is:

**Service:**

```
    public getAllPratiche(): Observable<any> {
    const url = `${environment.backendUrl}/pratiche/getAllPratiche/`;
    return this.http.get(url);
    }
```

and my component is:

**Component:**

```
 ngOnInit() {
this.praticaService.getAllPratiche()
  .subscribe(res => {
    this.pratiche = res.data;
    var prova = res.data;
      this.allEntity.forEach(elem => {
      var matchedEntity = this.getNumberMatchedEntity(prova, elem);
      var totalEntity = this.getNumberEntity(prova, elem);
      var percentage = matchedEntity / totalEntity * 100 + "%";
      this.results = [{
        entity: elem,
        percentage: percentage
      }];
    })
  }, err => {
    console.log('Error: ', err);
  })
}
```

Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: what is the exact problem you are facing ?

Comment: I am getting all the data. But i want only the data that match the conditions that I described above

Comment: please provide JSON data so anyone can play around